# python pandas calculate time until output goes below a set value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in python with several columns and a datetime stamp. Is it possible to count seconds until output goes below a set value (say 2)?

Ideally it would look something like this if the set value is 2:

```
 datetime               output     secondsuntilbelow
 2014-05-01 01:00:00    3         2
 2014-05-01 01:00:01    2         1
 2014-05-01 01:00:02    1         0
 2014-05-01 01:00:03    2         1
 2014-05-01 01:00:04    1         0
```

Comment: I recall this question setup, what have you tried? What have you learnt since asking/getting help last time. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: This question is different than the previous question I asked. In the previous question, I asked how to compute seconds until output decreased below its current level at each timestep; in this question i'm asking how to compute seconds until output decreases below a constant level not its current level. I tried the solutions that were posted, but I wasn't able to adapt any of them for this new problem.